# duplicates rows in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have done a translations api were our users can add translations to the system. 
A bug in the api added duplicate rows which i need to remove.

[image]

The translationConnection_Id combined with TranslationCompanyKey_Id is a key and therefor should not be able to be duplicate.
I since i'm a real sucker at SQL i need some help to create a script to remove all duplicates but saves one of the rows.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
  ,[Value]
  ,[TranslationConnection_Id]
  ,[TranslationCompanyKey_Id]
 FROM [AAES_TRAN].[dbo].[Translations]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: You have 2 different values in the `VALUE` field. How do you determine which to keep?

Comment: I do only need to save one of them, doesn't matter which one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will work. Try the SELECT part first to be sure.

```
DELETE FROM tblTranslations WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tblTranslations
    GROUP BY TranslationConnection_Id, TranslationCompanyKey_Id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function for this like

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
  ,[Value]
  ,[TranslationConnection_Id]
  ,[TranslationCompanyKey_Id]
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Value] ORDER BY [Value]) AS rn
 FROM [AAES_TRAN].[dbo].[Translations] ) xxx
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to keep one record from the duplicate records.

This code will delete duplicate records but will keep one records. Try this:

```
DELETE FROM TestTranslationTable WHERE ID IN(
     SELECT Id FROM TestTranslationTable tblMain
     WHERE tblMain.Id NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 tblNested.id FROM TestTranslationTable tblNested WHERE 
     tblNested.TranslationConnectionId=tblMain.TranslationConnectionId ORDER BY tblNested.TranslationConnectionId)
     AND tblMain.TranslationConnectionId IN(SELECT TranslationConnectionId FROM TestTranslationTable 
     GROUP BY TranslationConnectionId HAVING COUNT(TranslationConnectionId)>1 )
     )
     GO
```

Ref: https://jwcooney.com/2011/11/18/sql-server-delete-duplicate-records-except-the-first-duplicate-record/